# MATLAB custom datatip in images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Following the instructions on other pages, e.g.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/
http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html
http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68079-how-to-add-additional-info-to-the-data-cursor

i've written a custom callback function for the datatip to show me the index of the points on a x-y graph as well as their x and y coordinates:

```
function output_txt = customCallback_DataTip(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
else % 2D plot: write index of current point
    i = find(event_obj.Target.XData == pos(1), 1);
    output_txt{end+1} = ['i: ',num2str(i)];
end
```

This code starts from the default callback suggested by MATLAB, and adds a z-coordinate info whenever the plot is a 3D one. Since I very often need to know the array index of a point on a graph, the custom callback function is enabled automatically at MATLAB startup.

Now, whenever I plot an image (e.g. via `imagesc`) I would like to have the "normal" image datatip:

[image: image datatip]

i.e. with Index/RGB information on it. How can I modify the callback function in order to obtain this behavior?

**EDIT:** i would like to modify *my custom callback* so that it automatically displays something similar to the default MATLAB default datatip when I'm using the datatip on an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can check the type of the `event_obj.Target` and respond accordingly.

```
get(event_obj.Target, 'type')
```

All images (whether `imagesc`, `image`, or `imshow`) will have a `Type` of `image`.

```
isImage = strcmpi(get(event_obj.Target, 'type'), 'image')
```

You can then extract the image data. If you have an indexed image, you can also get the colormap to determine all the other information to go into the datatip.

```
cdata = get(event_obj.Target, 'cdata');
cmap = colormap(ancestor(event_obj.Target, 'axes'));
```

Bringing this all together, I would modify your custom data tip callback to be something like this.

```
function output_txt = callback(obj, event_obj, clims)
    % Get the cursor location
    pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');

    output_txt = {sprintf('[X,Y]: [%i, %i]', pos(1), pos(2))};

    if strcmpi(get(event_obj.Target, 'type'), 'image')
        % Get the image data
        cdata = get(event_obj.Target, 'CData');

        % Check to ensure pos is in range
        if pos(1) < 1 || pos(1) > size(cdata, 2) || ...
           pos(2) < 1 || pos(2) > size(cdata, 1)
            rgb = {NaN, NaN, NaN};
            newline = sprintf('[R,G,B]: [%0.4f %0.4f %0.4f]', rgb{:});
            output_txt = cat(1, output_txt, newline);
            return
        end

        % If the image is RGB
        if size(cdata, 3) == 3
            rgb = num2cell(cdata(pos(2), pos(1), :));

        % If this is an indexed image
        else
            index = cdata(pos(2), pos(1));

            % Figure out the colormap
            hax = ancestor(event_obj.Target, 'axes');
            cmap = colormap(hax);

            % If the CData is scaled, we need to scale to the colormap
            if strcmpi(get(event_obj.Target, 'CDataMapping'), 'scaled')
                value = (index - clims(1)) * size(cmap, 1) / diff(clims);
            else
                value = index;
            end

            % Determine RGB value from colormap
            rgb = num2cell(ind2rgb(round(value), cmap));

            if round(index) == index
                newline = sprintf('Index: %d', index);
            else
                newline = sprintf('Index: %.4f', index);
            end

            % Generate datatip text
            output_txt = cat(1, output_txt, newline);
        end

        output_txt = cat(1, output_txt, ...
                sprintf('[R,G,B]: [%0.4f %0.4f %0.4f]', rgb{:}));

    % Otherwise we use your custom datatip for plots
    else
        index = find(event_obj.Target.XData == pos(1), 1);

        pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
        output_txt = { sprintf('X: %0.4f', pos(1));
                       sprintf('Y: %0.4f', pos(2))};

        % If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
        if length(pos) > 2
            output_txt{end+1} = sprintf('Z: %0.4f', pos(3));
        else % 2D plot: write index of current point
            output_txt{end+1} = sprintf('i: %d', index);
        end
    end
end
```

If you notice, I'm passing in an additional variable (`clims`) to the callback function. This is because some versions won't actually allow me to query axes properties from *within* the datatip `UpdateFcn`. So this means that you will have to change your `UpdateFcn` anonymous function just a little bit.

```
h = datacursormode(fig);
set(h, 'Enable', 'on')

% Here I have to pass the `clims` because I can't fetch them inside
set(h, 'UpdateFcn', @(dt,e)callback(dt, e, caxis(ancestor(dt.Host, 'axes'))));
```

Using this, I was able to show the proper display for both plots and images (both indexed and RGB).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. More than I expected to do. Thaks so much!

Comment: Just in case someone else wants to copy-paste your code: after the last `else`, the following line is missing:
`i = find(event_obj.Target.XData == pos(1), 1);`

Comment: @lampo808 Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to include your code.